# How to show an alert before download a file

Tags: javascript, asp.net

This is my question i have an aspx page that has to show a popup message and when the user clicks ok begin download
any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a click handler on your link or button:

```
<a href="url/to/file.txt" onclick="return confirm('are you sure you want to download this file?');">file text</a>
```

working example: http://jsfiddle.net/QRgvV/

Answer (score 4):

Script

```
function download() {
    if (confirm ('Download file?')) {
        location.href = 'yourfile.pdf';
    }

    return false;
}
```

HTML

```
<a href='#' onclick='return download()'>Download</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript you will have to create a modal which instructs the user to click on a link within the modal to continue the download. You can't use JS to force a download to begin, due to security concerns. So the best you can do is give them a message and a second link which will actually trigger the download (when the user manually clicks on it).